# WPF Databinding making a color selector

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, colors

Hi I'm having a problem getting my WPF color selector to work. I think its because I'm suing Databinding in a wrong way but im not sure as I dont fully understand it.

What i want is a dropdown, that contains the colors in my list(contains as in shows the actual color not just text).

Heres my Code:

WPF:

```
<ComboBox Name="cb_farbe" Text="farbe" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Loaded="CbFarbe">

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Margin="5, 10" Fill="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>
```

c#:

```
private void CbFarbe(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        List<Color> colors = new List<Color>
        {
           Color.Blue,
           Color.Green,
           Color.LightBlue,
           Color.Black,
           Color.White,
           Color.Gray
        };

        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

        comboBox.ItemsSource = colors;

        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;

        this.DataContext = colors;

    }
```

Comment: Try `List<Brush>` and fill it with `Brushes.Blue` etc. Besides that, the Rectange has no size set.

Comment: @Clemens That way I just get the String "System.Drawing.SolidBrush in my default selected index and all the other options are blank"

Comment: I mean WPF Brushes, not WinForms Brushes, i.e. System.Windows.Media.Brushes. In general, you shouldn't use WinForms classes in a WPF application. Remove the System.Drawing assembly reference.

Comment: @Clemens I dont quite understand what you mena by that 
 was it something like this?
`List<System.Windows.Media.Brushes> colors = new List<System.Windows.Media.Brushes>
            {
               System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue,
               System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green,
               System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue,
               System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
               System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White,
               System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Gray
            };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure XAML solution. Note that you'll also have to set the width and height of the Rectangle:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="5,10" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <SolidColorBrush>Blue</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>Green</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>LightBlue</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>Black</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>White</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush>Gray</SolidColorBrush>
</ComboBox>
```

Note that the ComboBox's `SelectedItem` property would return a `SolidColorBrush`. If you actually want to have a `Color`, set

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedValuePath="Color">
```

and get the color by the `SelectedValue` property.

Answer (score 1):

The `Fill` property on `Rectangle` is of type `System.Windows.Media.Brush`. I suspect you'll see binding errors in your console output trying to bind `System.Drawing.Color` to it.

So what you need is a `System.Windows.Media.Brush` object instead. You'll have to either change the collection you're binding to, or you can construct the brush in the XAML:

```
<Rectangle>
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}" />
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

in which case you would bind to a `List<System.Windows.Media.Color>`.

Comment: This still just shows me the string System.Drawing.SolidBrush instead of the color

Comment: With `<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}" />` you would need a `List<System.Windows.Media.Color>` instead of `List<System.Drawing.Color>`. As said, remove the assembly reference `System.Drawing.dll`.

Comment: Now i get the hexcode of the color diplayed as a string but still no color

Comment: Are you still binding the colour to the brush? A solid colour brush doesn't render colours as hex codes!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Background` of the `ComboBoxItem` to a `SolidColorBrush`:

```
<ComboBox Name="cb_farbe" Text="farbe" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" Grid.Row="7" 
                  Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Loaded="CbFarbe">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</ComboBox>
```

---

```
private void CbFarbe(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<System.Windows.Media.Color> colors = new List<System.Windows.Media.Color>
            {
               System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue,
               System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green,
               System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightBlue,
               System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black,
               System.Windows.Media.Colors.White,
               System.Windows.Media.Colors.Gray
            };

    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    comboBox.ItemsSource = colors;

    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;

}
```